# Not able to query on ArcGIS Server REST query end point

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I have a map server published on ArcGIS Server and it has a `Poles` layer. It has following fields:

[image: Images of poles layer attributes]

Now when I am trying to run any query against this layer by passing queries like

```
Owner IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
Owner = 'Utility'
```

I am getting this error while I am sure the `Owner` is not NULL and all has value of `utility`

> Failed to execute query.

[image]

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "return fields" always has to be set. Are you setting it? I always add * in there when doing a quick and dirty test

Comment: @Dowlers Return fields doesn't *have* to be set. If left empty, the geometry and the display field will be returned by default.

Comment: @Berend Your right, it works without * at 10.5.1. I could have sworn at 10.3.1 I always had to enter * but I don't have an installation to test on. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Dowlers Actually that wouldn't have surprised me, but I just checked an old 10.2 installation and that works without `*` too. It's the `where` that's required, and of course, if you want to see some *useful* information, you need `*` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

the best way to check an ArcGIS REST API endpoint is to simply add Where 1=1. In this way you should be able to get every possible result.

If you add the * on the out fields as it is mentioned in the commends you will also get all the attributes.

Finally, If you want to check for strings the

> Owner = 'Utility'

should work. Check again as we discussed with all the output fields and you should be able to find the issue with this field.